# Oracle get id of updated record in trigger update

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the following trigger for update action.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER oferta_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE ON oferty
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  id_oferta     number (10);
  id_komis      number (10);
  id_test_komis number (10);
  suma          decimal(10,2) :=0;

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT cena_aktualna, id_test_komis
      FROM oferty
      WHERE status = 'A';
BEGIN
  id_oferta := :NEW.idk;
  dbms_output.put_line(id_oferta);

  SELECT komis_id INTO id_komis FROM oferty WHERE idk = id_oferta;

  FOR i in c1 LOOP
    IF i.id_test_komis = id_komis THEN
       suma := suma + i.cena_aktualna;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  UPDATE komisy SET wartosc_samochodow = suma WHERE idk = id_komis;
END;
```

During update operation.

```
UPDATE oferty SET status ='Z' WHERE idk =1;
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-04091: table OFERTY is mutating, trigger/function may
>   not see it.

How to solve the problem. I think this is problem of getting id.

Comment: The table `oferty`that is being modified cannot be queried not updated in FOR EACH ROW trigger. There are hundreds of articles on MUTATING TABLE ERROR, so I'm not going to explain it here. There is a workaround using COMPOUND trigger, you can find an example in [the documentation - Example 9-4 Compound Trigger that Avoids Mutating-Table Error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#CHDFEBFJ)

Comment: @krokodilko Any example, how get get id updated record in this trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example based on Scott's schema. I altered the DEPT table, adding a new column (SUM_SAL) which is supposed to contain sum of all salaries in that department.

First, the good, old *mutating table* way.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_sumsal
  2    after update on emp
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_sum number;
  6  begin
  7    select sum(sal) into l_sum
  8      from emp
  9      where empno = :new.empno;
 10
 11    update dept set sum_sal = l_sum
 12      where deptno = :new.deptno;
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL> update emp set sal = 5000 where ename = 'KING';
update emp set sal = 5000 where ename = 'KING'
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_SUMSAL", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_SUMSAL'


SQL>
```

As we already knew, that won't work.

Now, the compound trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_sumsal
  2    for update or insert on emp
  3    compound trigger
  4
  5    l_deptno emp.deptno%type;
  6
  7    after each row is
  8    begin
  9      l_deptno := :new.deptno;
 10    end after each row;
 11
 12    after statement is
 13      l_sum number;
 14    begin
 15      select sum(sal) into l_Sum
 16        from emp
 17        where deptno = l_deptno;
 18
 19      update dept set sum_sal = l_sum
 20      where deptno = l_deptno;
 21    end after statement;
 22  end;
 23  /

Trigger created.

SQL> update emp set sal = 10000 where ename = 'KING';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC              SUM_SAL
---------- -------------- ------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK           13750
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Nice; that works!

**[EDIT, after reading William's comment]**

If several departments are affected within a single UPDATE statement, the above code won't work properly. Slightly adjusted, it looks like this & fixes that issue:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_sumsal
  2    for update or insert on emp
  3    compound trigger
  4
  5    type t_tab is table of number;
  6    l_tab t_tab := t_tab();
  7
  8    after each row is
  9    begin
 10      l_tab.extend;
 11      l_tab(l_tab.last) := :new.deptno;
 12    end after each row;
 13
 14    after statement is
 15      l_sum number;
 16    begin
 17      for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 18        select sum(sal) into l_Sum
 19          from emp
 20          where deptno = l_tab(i);
 21
 22        update dept set sum_sal = l_sum
 23          where deptno = l_tab(i);
 24      end loop;
 25    end after statement;
 26  end;
 27  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC              SUM_SAL
---------- -------------- ------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> update emp set sal = 10000 where ename in ('SMITH', 'KING');

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC              SUM_SAL
---------- -------------- ------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK           13750
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS             15975
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Comment: What happens when an update affects more than one department?

Comment: Nothing, @William. It simply wouldn't work properly :) I've edited my message, I hope it is better now. Thank you for the remark!

Comment: Handling cross-table operations with triggers is a rabbit hole that can get very deep :-)  For example, see https://imgur.com/a/ayaVH with your current trigger

Comment: Yes, I agree, @Connor. I don't do such things ("keep sum of all salaries per department in the DEPT table"). Salary belongs to an employee, and - whenever I have to calculate sum of salaries per department - that's exactly what I do - I *calculate* it.

Comment: For efficiency (and aside from @ConnorMcDonald's point about whether any of this is a good idea), I would try declaring the array as `index by emp.deptno%type` and then use the array index rather than its values to record deptnos, so there will only be one array element per distinct deptno updated. Then you might be able to replace the loop with a `forall i in indices of l_tab`.